# android - How to programmatically read manifest intents?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, manifest

I'm trying to make a piece of code that will work across multiple apps.  I can't figure out how to read this from within Java, though.  Is it possible without parsing the manifest manually?  I want to grab scheme1 and scheme2 out with a few lines of code.

```
<activity android:name="urlHandlingBlah">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
        <data android:scheme="scheme1"></data>
        <data android:scheme="scheme2"></data>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Edit: I mean how would I use PackageManager to grab this info.  I don't care about the actual XML, per se.

Comment: I have this issue. This article explains how to create an intent, and then references it in code, but it doesn't explain how it magically got the reference (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html)

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not possible because once your app has been created everything gets converted to an APK, and that manifest is no longer readable at runtime. You can however read these properties interacting with the PackageManager though.

Comment: And to do this with the PackageManager, one would...?  Sorry, that's what I was trying to get at with my question.

Comment: Actually, no, intent filter information cannot be obtained from the package manager.  However from the deprecation of forward locking up until Jellybean you could get it by reading the .apk's and decoding their manifests, but from Jellybean apk's of other apps may no longer be readable.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I just want to read this from **my** app, preferably from all versions of the SDK.  Is that possible?

Comment: @xtravar, I'm still not understanding why you would need this information to "to make a piece of code that will work across multiple apps"? Also, aren't you the one writing these schemes into these manifests? Couldn't you just make these schemes string resources and just insert them into your manifests?